# Font Identification for script typeface

Tags: font-identification

I'm trying to find what font this is. I have check both Whatfont and Font Squirrel but I can't find it.

The letters below are `Isa`

[image: The image is Isa]

Answer (score 5):

[Pen Tweaks One](https://fontzone.net/font-details/pen-tweaks-one-ssi)  via Fontzone.net, I guess it's retouched with a stroke to make it **bolder**.

[image]

[image: Isabelle01]

[image: isabelle02]

[image: isabelle03]

This is Photoshop:
[image: photoshop sample]

Comment: Thank you so much. how to I get the stroke to make it bolder ?

Comment: @Klink Stroke width or "weight" of text objects is adjustable in graphics software such as Illustrator If you write in Windows Wordpad or other simple text editing software, the font is "as is" with very limited adjustment possiblities. Danielillo, can you reveal how you spotted this font as a close match?

Comment: I use Fontexplorer as font manager. All my fonts are classified by family. I wrote ISA on the sample field, choose "Scripts Family" on my font classification and roll down until found it.

Comment: Does adobe Photoshop 7.0 has this features  ?

Comment: Ass a layer effect. I add the sample image on the question.

Comment: @ Danielillo I mean does Adobe Photoshop 7.0 has this stroke features to bold the text ?

Comment: Not directly on the text, just as an effect on the text layer. Click twice the text layer and add the stroke.

Comment: @ Danielillo thank you so much for your response so far. Which adobe Photoshop would you recommend I download to be able to use the stroke features. It seem adobe Photoshop 7.0 has limitations.Thanks

Comment: @K link Always the last... as far as i check on Wikipedia there are 23 versions after Photoshop 7! Anyway, i guess any CS or CC versions have this feature. Question: from where did you get this little sample picture you put on your question? It seems an old printing.

Comment: @ Danielillo I saw the picture online and I love the font.I have downloaded Adobe Photoshop 2017 but still I can't bold the front using stroke it becomes blurred .Can you explain step by step procedure?

Comment: @K link Double click on the text layer to add a Layer Style > select Stroke from the list of Styles > Choose size and Position Outside

Answer (score 0):

I found some similar fonts but they are not *exact*. I based them off from the line variations and the flourish of the 'I' in your sample.

Also, I'm not sure if your image is pulled from a website or from another image, but if it's the latter, the "font" could also possibly be handwritten as calligraphy?

**Here are some alternatives**:

[One Fell Swoop](https://www.dafont.com/one-fell-swoop.font?) via dafont.

[image]

[Bickham Script](https://typekit.com/fonts/bickham-script) via Adobe Typekit.

[image]

[Commercial Script STD](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/commercial-script/commercial-script/) via MyFonts.

[image]